# Android Framework modification : Adding a custom layout

Tags: android, layout, frameworks

I am trying to add a new layout to the framework say my_layout.

I succeeded partially in that .

I defined my layout in an xml and put it inside **frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout**

I then mentioned the id in **frameworks/base/core/res/res/values**
**public.xml and ids.xml**

And after performing a complete build :

> make framework
>
> make update-api
>
> make

i am able to access it as **android.R.layout.my_layout**

But now i want to access it through xml also :Eg: "**@android:layout/my_layout"**

In which place in the source do i mention this reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the id in your my_layout.xml file in your layout folder.

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    ...
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: i have already defined it ! And its not in application side . I am talking from the framework side

Comment: Can you give more information on what exactly you want to do with the layout? Might be easier to do what you want to do through code rather than xml as the xml files for android are usually used to define variables and layouts.